# How to loop through the option set in js

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

I am taking the option set selected values using javascript. I have taken it in a variable but need to loop through the variable and if the loop contains one particular value among the list, then do an action.

```
        var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
        let selectedItem = formContext.getAttribute("currentactivity").getValue();
        alert(selectedItem);
        if(selectedItem == 8)){
            formContext.getControl("currentcomments").setVisible(true);
        } else
        {
            formContext.getControl("currentcomments").setVisible(false);
        }
```

in this, the selected items will have a list of values among (0-8). My code just looking at the first value not looping through all.

Can someone of you guide me in this

Comment: Use either [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Array.prototypr.includes worked :). Thanks @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Array.prototype.includes(), and it worked.

```
if( selectedItem.includes(8))
    {
        formContext.getControl("currentcomments").setVisible(true);
    } else
    {
        formContext.getControl("currentcomments").setVisible(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can adapte this:

for(var index = 0;index<content.length;index++){
If(content [index].value == something){
You code here
}}
I'm sorry, I'm on mobile.

Comment: for(var index = 0;index<selectedItem.length;index++)
            { 
            if(selectedItem [index].value == 926750008)
            { formContext.getControl("currentcomments").setVisible(true);
         } else {
            formContext.getControl("currentcomments").setVisible(false);
         }
like this?